# ordered list of user controls (with addition and deletion)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

**Some context**

I am creating an application which allows users create basic shelving arrangements, I wish to create an interface which represents shelving blocks(one set of shelves) next to each other in order (left to right) and allows users to edit their details.
Each block will have a series of details such as its order,a name, a width, a height and a number of shelves.

**Requirements**

I want the interface to have a horizontal scrolling list of (max 20) user controls. Each user control will represent the details of a block, with a basic form for these details to be edited.

The user should be able to press a button in the user control which deletes it and reorders the other blocks and also add blocks to the end of the list.

**My Question**

How do I maintain an ordered list of these 'shelf block' user controls, and have the form handle the pressing of the deletion button in any of the controls which causes it to be deleted and the list to be reordered? Any help would be great.

**Screenshot**

I am just starting to program the interface so I can only provide a quick mock up of what I want the interface to look like:

[image]

as basic as it is I hope it gives you some idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Updated with a screen design.

Comment: [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx), if you want to handle data binding manually. Or [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488280.aspx). I never used `DataRepeater` myself, but it should be fairly rich in features, according to MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) to store your blocks. A BindingList will notify the UI control (e.g. a ListBox) that data has been changed such as a block being deleted. The UI will then reflect this by removing the block from the ListBox. If you're familiar with WPF/Silverlight databinding this is similar to, but not quite the same as, an `ObservableCollection` list (if you're targetting `.NET 4`, I believe you may be able to use ObserverableCollections in a WinForm without much trouble but someone else may be able to clarify that).

Alternatively, you can use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) instead of directly using a `BindingList`.

Comment: Hi, thaks for your quick answer,I was thinking that a flowlayoutpanel suited user controls more? Seeing as I do not need to deal with these controls being selected etc, just laid out horizontally. Do you agree? if so from what I have read I don't think a bindinglist would work with a flow layout panel?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it a bit mixed up. I assumed you wanted a data structure to hold and maintain the boxes which can then be displayed on the UI. You could use a FlowLayoutPanel if you like but it would mean interacting directly with the UI whenever you want to remove a control (e.g. by calling FLowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove()) and not with an underlying data structure.

Comment: Yeah it turns out I was making the problem more complicated than it needed to be. A flowlayout full of usercontrols was all that was needed, removing the UC to delete. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a hidden grid control on your form.
Then you just add/ remove rows to the grid with the desired data
and everything is kept very orderly.   One advantage here is that
for debugging purposes you can always make the grid visible to see
all the data quickly.